# Split words in a column using Regex in R

Tags: r, split

I have a hypothetical dataframe that contains columns `hashtags` and `username`.

```
hashtags <- c("['mancity', 'naomicampell']","['PaTvUpdates']","['SputnikV']","['sputnikvaccineregistration', 'UnlockOurCountry', 'AstraZeneca', 'coronaInaua']",
              "['Africa', 'Sinopharm', 'Sinopham', 'vaccine', 'vaccinedeaths']", "['Sinopharm', 'COVID']")
username <- c("a","b","z","x","d","w")
twts <- data.frame(hashtags, username)
```

I'd like to split the hashtags so that I can get the frequency count of each hashtag present in the column `hashtag`. How do I do that?

I don't have reproducible code as I'm new to regex

Comment: Are spaces within hashtags allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `stringr`

```
library(stringr)

str_remove_all(twts$hashtags, "[^ \\w+]") |> 
  str_split(" ") |> unlist() |> table()

                    Africa                AstraZeneca 
                         1                          1 
               coronaInaua                      COVID 
                         1                          1 
                   mancity               naomicampell 
                         1                          1 
               PaTvUpdates                   Sinopham 
                         1                          1 
                 Sinopharm                   SputnikV 
                         2                          1 
sputnikvaccineregistration           UnlockOurCountry 
                         1                          1 
                   vaccine              vaccinedeaths 
                         1                          1
```

Preserves spaces within tags

```
str_split(twts$hashtags, ",") |> unlist() |> str_remove_all("[^ \\w+]") |> 
  str_squish() |> table()
```

Answer (score 2):

With the help of `py_eval`, we can parse the words in a python way

```
> library(reticulate)

> with(twts, table(unlist(lapply(hashtags, py_eval))))

                    Africa                AstraZeneca
                         1                          1
               coronaInaua                      COVID
                         1                          1
                   mancity               naomicampell
                         1                          1
               PaTvUpdates                   Sinopham
                         1                          1
                 Sinopharm                   SputnikV
                         2                          1
sputnikvaccineregistration           UnlockOurCountry
                         1                          1
                   vaccine              vaccinedeaths
                         1                          1
```

or

```
> with(twts, table(unlist(py_eval(sprintf("[%s]", toString(hashtags))))))

                    Africa                AstraZeneca
                         1                          1 
               coronaInaua                      COVID
                         1                          1
                   mancity               naomicampell
                         1                          1
               PaTvUpdates                   Sinopham
                         1                          1
                 Sinopharm                   SputnikV
                         2                          1
sputnikvaccineregistration           UnlockOurCountry
                         1                          1
                   vaccine              vaccinedeaths
                         1                          1
```

Comment: I'm actually using reticulate on this project,  running tensorflow in R. Let me try this

Answer (score 1):

Extract the words with gregexpr/regmatches, `unlist` the list to a vector and use `table` to get the frequency count in `base R`

```
table(unlist(with(twts, regmatches(hashtags, gregexpr('[A-Za-z]+', hashtags)))))
```

-output

```
                    Africa                AstraZeneca                coronaInaua                      COVID                    mancity 
                         1                          1                          1                          1                          1 
              naomicampell                PaTvUpdates                   Sinopham                  Sinopharm                   SputnikV 
                         1                          1                          1                          2                          1 
sputnikvaccineregistration           UnlockOurCountry                    vaccine              vaccinedeaths 
                         1                          1                          1                          1
```

---

Or in a pipe

```
with(twts, regmatches(hashtags, gregexpr('[A-Za-z]+', hashtags))) |> 
   unlist() |>
   table()
```